# Int array to string for strtol

Tags: c, string, int, strtol

I want to get

```
int sign[8]= {0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1};
```

to use on strtol function like

```
char c = (char) strtol(sign, NULL, 2);
printf("%c\n", c);
```

I have no idea how to cast sign to use in strol. When I'm using

```
 c = (char) strtol("01010111", NULL, 2);
```

everything is ok and I want to get such result.

Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `sign` is not a string, it's an array of small integers.

You can interpret them directly as bits and convert the array into a number, there's no point in going via `strtol()` (and, in fact, it's rather un-idiomatic in C to do it your way).

Just loop:

```
unsigned int array_to_int(const int *bits, size_t num_bits)
{
  unsigned int ret = 0, value = 1;
  for(; num_bits > 0; --num_bits, value *= 2)
    ret += value * bits[num_bits - 1];
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: You could also writhe it with bitwise operators. In this case I think it's more clear. `ret |= bits[num_bits-1] << pos;`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this

```
int sign[8]= {0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1};
```

to

```
char sign[9]= {'0','1','0','1','0','1','1','1','\0'};
```

the way you had it you was using the ascii value `1` instead if the character `'1'`, and you should add a null terminating byte `'\0'` so the array can be used as a string.

And then, you can

```
char c = (char) strtol(sign, NULL, 2);
printf("%c\n", c);
```

Comment: yes, its working but i want to know how to cast from int sign[8] to char sign[8] :( checked few solutions from google and everything was wrong

Comment: @user2973468 Why would you want to cast?

Comment: because I have all program working on that int array and now i want to know how to cast/copy it to char array

Comment: It's impossible to help you without knowing more, you should not do such cast because `sizeof(char) != sizeof(int)` and it violates strict aliasing rules. You can do it the other way around from `int *` to `unsigned char *`, but that works only with `unsigned char *` AFAIK. Or you can use `void *` instead.

Comment: ok, but simply can you tell me how to copy 
int sign[8]= {0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1}; to char sign[9]= {'0','1','0','1','0','1','1','1','\0'};  ?

Comment: @user2973468 `int i; int sign_int[8]= {0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1}; char sign[9]= {'0','1','0','1','0','1','1','1','\0'}; for (i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++) sign[i] = (char)sign_int[i] + '0'; sign[8] = '\0';` This is the only way I can think of, the cast would not make it possible.